# Loading bulk data into neo4j with Neography results in connection error

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neography

I'm trying to read a lot of bulk data (probably around 1-2G) into neo4j with a simple ruby script and Neography. My code mostly just consists of a lot of create_node and create_relationship methods.

It seems to work fine, but after around 5,000 create methods I reach an error:

```
/home/earlz/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.44.3/lib/excon/socket.rb:127:in `connect_nonblock': Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7474 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
```

How do I fix this? I've tried increasing the HTTP timeouts and such, but this didn't help anything

Comment: You might also want to check out neo4api ( https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis )

Comment: Interesting @BrianUnderwood.. would that also handle very large data without running out of memory.. my eventual target dataset will probably be around 50G

Comment: You'd need to load data from the source in some way as to not use too much memory (like loading a file a link/chunk at a time or using something like ActiveRecord's `find_in_batches` to get data from a database), but neo4apis takes what you give it and does `MERGE` commands in batches according to the `batch_size` which is set.  It sends the commands to the Neo4j batch statement endpoint

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your script is opening so many connections that it ran out of ephemeral ports to pick from. Try this:

```
echo "32768 61000" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```